# Unchallengingly accept - easily or without dispute?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

*[...] **Unchallengingly**, we accept that the rose is beautiful, though it must be said that roses in the wild can make some garden varieties look almost vulgar*.(Cambridge English, Objective Proficiency)

What does 'unchallengingly' mean in this case? Do we easily accept that the rose is beautiful (since the adjective 'unchallenging' means easy), or rather do we not challenge this fact?

Thank you!

Comment: Unchallengingly here is synonymous with "uncritically/unquestioningly "

Comment: A similar take to @JOSH. "That the rose is beautiful" is a belief (or opinion) that many people hold; it is not a "fact" in the usual sense of the word. When people who hold such a belief hear or see it expressed in statements such as "The rose is beautiful", they don't think (it wouldn't occur to them) to question or challenge such statements: they take it for granted (as true) that "the rose is beautiful". They accept such statements without question or challenge, i.e., unquestioningly or unchallengingly.

Comment: Good question, +1. Personally I think it could be taken as "Like sheep, we unchallengingly accept [whatever, but maybe we shouldn't]."

Answer (score 1):

Something is ***[​unchallenged](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unchallenged)***  when it is:

> - ***accepted without asking questions or criticizing***:
>   *We can't allow her comments to go unchallenged.*

Cambridge Dictionary

- The idea is that you passively accept the idea  that the rose is beautiful despite the fact  roses in the wild can be remarkably more beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

Unchallengingly in the sentence meant undoubtingly or unquestionably. Without a doubt, we accept the rose is beautiful. Without questioning, we accept the rose is beautiful.

Comment: Where did you get your answer? Unless you cite a source, it's unclear why your answer is correct. Please look at the [help center's page on how to write a good answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).